# Displaying values that occur consecutively

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to display a list of all Directors who have directed 2 years consecutively.

Given the following data:

```
Pantomime table:
Year   titleID  DirectorID
2000    1         1
2001    2         7
2002    3         7
2003    4         8
2004    5         9
2005    6         9
```

This is the desired outcome:

```
DirectorID
   7
   9
```

This is the query I have tried so far but was unable to get the desired results.

```
SELECT directorID
FROM pantomime
where directorID = directorID+1
GROUP BY directorID
```

Comment: Two consecutive years or titles?

Comment: Consecutive years.  So essentially, year 2001 directorID 7, year 2002 directorID 7, year 2004 directorID 9, year 2005 directorID 9

Comment: It's just a simple join

Answer (score 5):

One method uses `exists`:

```
select distinct p.directorId
from pantomine p
where exists (select 1
              from pantomine p2
              where p2.directorId = p.directorId and p2.year = p.year + 1
             );
```

There are other fun variants on this idea, such as using `in`:

```
select distinct p.directorId
from pantomine p
where p.year in (select p2.year + 1
                 from pantomine p2
                 where p2.directorId = p.directorId
                );
```

And here is a totally arcane method that doesn't use join-like mechanisms at all (just aggregation):

```
select distinct directorId
from ((select directorId, year from pantomine)
      union all
      (select directorId, year + 1 from pantomine)
     ) p
group by directorId, year
having count(*) = 2;
```

This is also one of those really, really rare cases of using `select distinct` with `group by`.

Answer (score 3):

you can use join to see which entries has the next year's value, and then with distinct get the relevant id's:

```
select distinct a.directorID 
from Pantomime as a 
inner join Pantomime as b on a.year = b.year-1 
                         and a.directorID = b.directorID;
```

since I'm using *inner* join, we'll get records from a only if they exist in b- meaning if `year-1` appears in your table for this directorId

Comment: This seems like the most elegant solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, no joins or sub-queries, just a simple grouping:

```
SELECT directorID
FROM pantomime
GROUP BY directorID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
AND MAX(Year) = MIN(Year) + 1
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/396506/508243/).